# System.Exception when clearing items in Flipview

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

So i was trying to clear my items in a flipview using `Items.Clear()`. but then an error always shows "`System.Exception`" when trying to clear items. This is my Code:

```
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Clear();
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        var files = await openPicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();


        if (files != null)

        {
            //foreach (StorageFile Images in files)
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
            Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
              //Some imagedecoder here
               BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
                    img.SetSource(outStream);
              }


            }
         flpcakeimages.Items.Clear(); //System.Exception error here it says'Catastrophic error'
         flpCakeImages.ItemsSource = images;
```

Is that a proper way to update the flipview? I used the `.UpdateLayout` but it still not working, can you guys please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace

```
flpcakeimages.Items.Clear();
```

with

```
flpCakeImages.ItemsSource = null;
```

If you cant to replace the contents of flipView, just do like this:

```
flpCakeImages.ItemsSource = oldDataSource;
flpCakeImages.ItemsSource = null;
flpCakeImages.ItemsSource = newDataSource;
```

Comment: thanks! it answered half of my question,it nicely updates my flipview now the problem is, i want to clear the contents of flipview and replace the contents of it. how will i do that?

Comment: or you can try to replace you datasource. but your datasource must be a ObservableCollection.

Comment: and now my code bugs when i try to navigate to my picture it returns to the 1st picture why does that happen?

Comment: what do you mean by navigate to your picture? you can set the selected index of flipview.

Comment: i mean flipping through the flipview. but many thanks to you for helping me! :) i've tweaked my code a bit and its now replacing and updating my flipview.